# Modify values of an object created from a different class and send it to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to IOS Development. I have  a class `UserDetails` which contains details of a user like `id`, `name`, `type` etc. I want to create its object in another class and modify some of the parameters and then send the details in the `NSDictionary` which finally sends it in the json format to the server. Can you tell me how to do it?

Here's what I am doing:

```
NSDictionary * UserReference = [[UtilityClass sharedInstance] createUserDictionary:userDetails];
```

I want to know how to initialize the `userDetails` object(from the `UserDetails` class) and then modify its values(`int` and `string`) in another class.

Comment: Is your application a navigation based application?

Comment: you question seems to wrong.the following lines.. I want to create its object in another class & how to initialize the userDetails object(from the UserDetails class) !!!

Comment: yes
In the UserDetails class I have items like username, userid,usertype.
So in another class (different view) I am initializing an object and changing the values like this:

In the ViewDidLoad method: 

userDetails = [[UserDetails alloc] init];
userDetails.userid = [NSNumber numberWithInit:10];   (rest all parameters are same )
NSDictionary * UserReference = [[UtilityClass sharedInstance] createUserDictionary:userDetails];

Comment: what you mean exactly ? nitialize the userDetails object(from the UserDetails class) and then modify its values ? or create its object in another class and modify some of the parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to study more details about OOPS concepts

When you call **alloc and init** again to UserDetails class, the old values ( username, userid,usertype ) will lose. because  you are creating a **new object** for UserDetails class which is already created.

So try to pass the earlier created UserDetails object(as a parameter of a method or any other way) to the class  where you planning to modify the properties again.

Comment: why can't I do this directly without allocating memory in viewDidLoad.
like:

userDetails.userId=[NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
NSLog(@"%i", [userDetails.userId intValue];

Comment: UserDetails *userDetails has been declared in the interface of this class.

Comment: So you have to set the UserDetails value when allocating this class. Please write the @property for  the variable and use MyCurrentClass *myCurrentClass = [[MyCurrentClass alloc] init]; [myCurrentClass set userDetails:oldUserDetails];  hope you understood.. :)